# Bounded Display using C#

Tags: c#, projector

Way to create an application which will display only bounded content via projector.
Simple Scenario - I have one form in C#, having picture box property. I want only picture to be displayed via projector not the whole desktop view/form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should display one form on the last screen on your system, filling it up completely without anything but the PictureBox showing up:

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
   this.Text = "";
   this.ControlBox = false;
   this.MinimizeBox = false;
   pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

   // if you want the form to display on the last screen try this:
   this.Location = Screen.AllScreens
                  [Screen.AllScreens.Length - 1].WorkingArea.Location;

}
```

You'll have to decide on the `pictureBox1.SizeMode`..

Of course you'll have to know, which of your screens is set to be primary.

Comment: No, On my laptop I'll see the Desktop view, but on projected screen I'll see only the image.

Comment: Yes! What can be the best solution for doing it?